# "Extended" vs. "extensive"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, confusables

What's the difference between these two? I found the following after some research,

> “Extended” has to do with time, “extensive” with space. An extended tour lasts  a long time; an extensive tour covers a lot of territory.

But in the definition of "extended", it seems that it can also mean to enlarge or stretch in space. Any ideas?

Comment: An extensive tour may last a long time as well. And what might an extended hand have to do with time? Did you consult a dictionary?

Comment: He extended his collection by adding two more to his extensive collection of antique cars.

Answer (score 1):

Extended means to add extra.

***[extend](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/extend)***

> To stretch or spread (something) out to greater or fullest length: *extended the radio antenna.*

Extensive means that something is very well covered.

***[extensive](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/extensive?q=extensive)***

> covering or affecting a large area: *an extensive garden*

An extended tour lasts one hour more than a normal tour and is very extensive.

Also extended is not just for time.

Examples:  I extended my arm out.  The tape measure extends up to 25 feet.

The tape measure could be described as extensive if it had many different useful markings on it that helped measure things to the maximum.

Comment: Source? Always cite your sources.

Answer (score 0):

***[extent](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/extent?q=extent)*** *n.* [in singular]

> the area covered by something: *an enclosure ten acres in extent*
>   the degree to which something has spread; the size or scale of something

Whence ***[extensive](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/extensive?q=extensive)*** *adj.*

> **1** covering or affecting a large area: *an extensive garden*

Compare:

***[extend](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/extend)***

> **2**. To stretch or spread (something) out to greater or fullest length: *extended the radio antenna.*

Whence ***[extended](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/extended)*** *adj.*

> **2**. Continued for a long period of time; protracted: *had an extended vacation in the Alps.*

Any use of *extended* in a spatial sense is merely an extension of its basic meaning in a linear sense. (Dictionaries may place the spatial definition before the linear definition, though. Maybe there's a good reason for that as well!)